# Instance Variables Are Not Shared Between Processes in Python

Tags: python, oop, multiprocessing, multi-level

I have a big problem with Multi Processing. in this case I have a

1.Main Class in Main Process

2.Foo Class in Another Process

I Have To Change Some Variables Inside of Process2 With Main Process.
How Can I Do That/???

```
class Main:
     def __init__(self):
          self.Foo_Instance = Foo()
          multiprocessing.Process(target=self.Foo_Instance.do_something).start()

     def Change_Foo(self):
          Foo_Instance.ImportantVar = True
    
class Foo:
     def __init__(self):
          self.ImportantVar = False

     def do_something(self):
          pass

Main_Instance = Main()
Main_Instance.Change_Foo()
```

Comment: That is not relevant to my question bro.

Comment: This was a typo. My question is about MultiProcessing and update Variables from another PID.

Comment: A `multiprocessing.Manager` provides functionality to share values, lists or namespaces between processes: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#managers

Comment: The (original) title does not represent a problem -- instance variables aren't _supposed_ to be shared between processes, so it's describing normal and correct operation. Maybe reword into a question ("How can I share instance variables between processes in Python?")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each process in general has its own memory that is inaccessible to any other process. If you want one process to be able to modify a variable that another process is using, then the simplest solution is to create this variable in *shared memory*. In the demo below we create such a variable using a [`multiprocessing.Value`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value) instance. To demonstrate that `Main.Change_Foo` can modify `Foo`'s `ImportantVar` attribute, we have to give `Foo.do_something` a chance to print out its initial value before `Main.Change_Foo` modifies it. Likewise, `Foo.do_something` needs to wait for `Main.Change_Foo` to change the value before it prints out the updated value. To accomplish this we use two ['multiprocessing.Event'](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Event) instances:

```py
import multiprocessing
import ctypes
import time

class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Foo_Instance = Foo()
        multiprocessing.Process(target=self.Foo_Instance.do_something).start()

    def Change_Foo(self):
        # Wait for Foo.do_something to have printed out its initial value:
        self.Foo_Instance.initial_print_event.wait()

        # Modify the attribute (add missing self):
        self.Foo_Instance.ImportantVar.value = True

        # Show that we have modified the attribute:
        self.Foo_Instance.changed_event.set()


class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ImportantVar = multiprocessing.Value(ctypes.c_bool, False, lock=False)
        self.initial_print_event = multiprocessing.Event()
        self.changed_event = multiprocessing.Event()

    def do_something(self):
        print('do_something before:', self.ImportantVar.value)
        # Show that we have completed printing our initial value:
        self.initial_print_event.set()

        # Now wait for Main.Change_Foo to have changed our variable:
        self.changed_event.wait()

        print('do_something after:', self.ImportantVar.value)


# Required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main_Instance = Main()
    Main_Instance.Change_Foo()
```

Prints:

```None
do_something before: False
do_something after: True
```